# How do I make boolean based control decisions from a cmdlet that returns non-boolean results?

Tags: powershell, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

The code speaks for itself in regards to what I am trying to do. How do I make an if statement work in a Boolean fashion based on the results of a commandlet such as get-hotfix? Essentially, I want the True to be ANY result, and the false to be a null return.

I BELIEVE PowerShell already does this in that any result is always considered a Boolean true and no result is returned as a null. I need to know the syntax at `if ($hot -EQ True)` that won't error.

```
#get a list of computernames
$inputFile = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the directory path of the input file."
#parse the list of computernames into an array.
$info = Get-Content $inputFile

#loop to run the hotfix check against all the computers.
foreach ($Data in $info) {
  $hot =  Get-HotFix -ComputerName $Data | Where-Object hotfixid -EQ KB4338824
    #if patch is found output true to user
    if ($hot -EQ True){
      Write-Host $Data + "is True"    
    }
    #if patch is not found output false to user
    else {
      Write-Host $Data + "is False" 
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Please show us what is in the input file. Is that a list of computernames maybe? Then why test for a certain hotfix on just one computer named `$Data` and then do a foreach to test if `$hot` which you defined ABOVE the loop is $null or not? It doesn't make any sense to me..

Comment: I actually moved $hot outside the loop for testing earlier before I posted this. It should be in the loop, I will edit. Also yes the content of the input file is a list of server names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing ***speaking*** variable names helps understanding code a lot.

- one way to check a property value is `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()`
- I'd check the ID directly with `Get-Hotfix` no `Where-Object` required.
- and use a `[PSCustomObject]@{}` to return a table easily saved as a csv file.
- `-EA 0` is an abbreviation for `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\04\SO_52649161.ps1

$ComputerList = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the directory path of the input file."
$Computers    = Get-Content $ComputerList
$Hotfix       = 'KB4338824'

$result = ForEach($Computer in $Computers){
    $Installed = (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(
        (Get-HotFix -ID $Hotfix -Computer $Computer -EA 0).InstalledOn)))
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Computer  = $Computer
        Hotfix    = $Hotfix
        Installed = $Installed
    }
}
$result
$result | Export-Csv -Path HotFixSummary.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output

```
Computer Hotfix    Installed
-------- ------    ---------
PC1      KB4338824     False
PC2      KB4338824      True
```

Comment: I didn't think a total re-write would be needed but this does accomplish what I am looking to do. Thanks you very much!